# Submit button has to be in the same form as email/pw field?

Tags: php

I´m quite new to php so this might just be a stupid question. Is there a way to put the submit button into another form field, or must it be the same? Does it really matter if I create a new  field somewhere else?

Not working Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="post">
              <div class="form-group">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailfield" id="emailfeld2" placeholder="Emailadresse (z.B Max@Max.de)">

                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordfield" id="passwortfeld" placeholder="Passwort">

                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="cpasswordfield" id="cpasswortfeld" placeholder="Passwort bestätigen">




            </div>
      </form>

    <div class="form-group">
        <form method="post">    
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submitgo">Sign Up!</button>
        </form>    

    </div>


</div>


      <?php  
     echo $_POST['emailfield']."<br>";
    ?>


<div class="container-opacity">

</div>
```

Working code:

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="post">
              <div class="form-group">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailfield" id="emailfeld2" placeholder="Emailadresse (z.B Max@Max.de)">

                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordfield" id="passwortfeld" placeholder="Passwort">

                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="cpasswordfield" id="cpasswortfeld" placeholder="Passwort bestätigen">



              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submitgo">Sign Up!</button>
        </div>
        </form>    




</div>


      <?php  
     echo $_POST['emailfield']."<br>";
    ?>


<div class="container-opacity">

</div>
```

Comment: You could look at adding some jQuery to submit 2 forms with one button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally bad practice to have form elements outside of the form they belong to. It will work if you only have one `<form>` tag and move it outside of you main `<div class="container">`

```html
<form method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">

      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailfield" id="emailfeld2" placeholder="Emailadresse (z.B Max@Max.de)">

      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordfield" id="passwortfeld" placeholder="Passwort">

      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="cpasswordfield" id="cpasswortfeld" placeholder="Passwort bestätigen">

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submitgo">Sign Up!</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>

<?php echo $_POST[ 'emailfield']. "<br>"; ?>

<div class="container-opacity">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I fully understand it now!